# package-info.java for Spring component scan

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to define a root package for Spring components auto scan.

I don't like approach to define package name as a not type safe string. Currently I put artificial empty `Scannable` marker interface in the root of my package and use it in Spring `@ComponentScan` annotation in type safe way.

But is it possible to use `package-info.java` somehow in `@ComponentScan` annotation for the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax in Java which would allow you to directly reference a `Package` object by itself, so the short answer to your question is **no**.

You can't use `package-info.java` to reference a package in a manner which guarantees you compile-time safety. You can only reference a `Class` object directly and obtain its package through that `Class` object. And you can't put a class into `package-info.java` either, since java source file named `package-info.java` should contain at least a class named `package-info` if any, but that's not possible either, since 1) `-` is not allowed as a java identifier character and 2) `package` is a reserved keyword in java, as per the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).

Using a placeholder class or interface is the proper solution in this case which provides you with the most guarantees you can achieve in this situation.